# When is x+y+z-1/x-1/y-1/z cyclotomic?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Frame: I'm fighting with the "E7 family" again and look for spurious alternative
solutions to the most general setup. 
One requirement seems to be that $uv+uw+vw-1/u/v-1/u/w-1/v/w$ is a cyclotomic
polynomial (times t^whatever), where $u=t^i,v=-t^j,w=-t^k$, t free variable, i,j,k integer.
The E7 solution corresponds to $w=-1/u^3$, BTW, but if you compute now, you notice a
factor $v^2+vw+w^2$, so the cyclotomicity doesn't come out *totally* trivial. 
There are many other solutions, e.g. $w=-u$, and cyclotomicity isn't sufficient at all,
but maybe *this* problem here can be solved to give a finite list of admissible equations
in i,j,k and there are no others. (This would probably solve my original problem too,
since integer dimensions force further divisibility rules.)
Obviously my knowledge of number theory isn't better than that of knot theory - is this a viable way to attack?

Comment: What do you mean by a cyclotomic polynomial in several variables?

Comment: She seems to mean that there is a substitution $x=t^i, y=t^j, z=t^k$ which makes it cyclotomic [one variable] polynomial.

Comment: Right. (Except that I, only for the question, used x=uv,y=uw,z=vw as shorthand, and the +-- signature is essential. Was a bit misleading, I guess. Oh, and she is a he, but since on Internet everybody is a dog, it hardly matters :-)